# How do i update same field when it is array of object in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is example of field:

Document1:

```
comments: [
      {
           "_id": "6040840",
           "user_id": "600d4fd",
           "text": "very nice post",
           "res_comment": [
            {
                "_id": "39834",
                "user_id": "6acd4fd",
                "text": "thanks"
             },
             {
               "_id": "6983b9634",
               "user_id": "6005afd",
               "text": "yeah!!"
             }
           ]
      },
      {
           "_id": "6040840a",
           "user_id": "6004fd",
           "text": "very nice post",
           "res_comment": [
            {
                "_id": "3983b9634",
                "user_id": "6acd4fd",
                "text": "thanks"
             },
             {
               "_id": "6983b9",
               "user_id": "6005afd",
               "text": "yeah!!"
             }
           ]
      }
]
```

So now i want to pull from comments
index 0 whole element which _id `6040840` and
index 1 only pull res_comment which _id `6983b9`
In single Update query.
Anyone having solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

$ https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "res_comment._id": "6983b9634"
},
{
  $set: {
    "res_comment.$.text": "hello"
  }
})
```